# create new column based on relative rank

Tags: r, rank

i want to create a new column based on relative rank of reward column for each subject, but if the gamble is duplicated with different reward, than the rank will follow the highest rank.

This is my data and the new column should look like.

```
     subj gamble reward newcolumn
 1     1      1    1.5       3.0
 2     1      2    2.0       1.0
 3     1      1    0.0       3.0
 4     1      3    1.0       4.5
 5     1      1    0.0       3.0
 6     1      4    1.0       4.5
 7     2      2    5.0       1.0
 8     2      1    0.5       2.5
 9     2      4    0.0       4.0
 10    2      1    0.0       1.5
```

so far, I got this code,

```
 newdata<-transform(newdata, 
      reward.rank = ave(reward, subj, 
                      FUN = function(x) rank(-x, )))
```

but that is not really what I want.
as can be seen from the example above, if the gamble is repeated,and i want the rank follow the highest rank. for example, fr subject number one, gamble 1 has reward 1.5 and 0, the rank 0 will follow the higher rank, that is 3.

is that possible to do in R?
Thank you very much in advance

this is the reproducible data:

```
subj<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
gamble<-c(1,2,1,3,1,4,2,1,4,1)
reward<-c(1.5,2,0,1,0,1,5,0.5,0,0)
new<-data.frame(subj, gamble, reward)
```